# time complexity for check if string has only unique chars

Tags: python-3.x, time-complexity

This is an algorithm to determine if a string has all unique characters. What is the time complexity?

```
def unique(s):
    d = []
    for c in s:
        if c not in d:
            d.append(c)
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

Looks like it only one for loop here so it should be O(n), however, this line

```
 if c not in d:
```

does this line also cost O(n) time, if so, the time complexity for this algorithm is O(n^2) ?

Comment: If d is a list, then lookup in linear `O(n)` every time you call `if c not in d`. You do this `n` times. So, `n * n = n^2`. You are correct, the if statement is a linear time search. If you were to use a set, the if statement would be `O(1)`. So `n * 1 = n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is correct, this algorithm is *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. The [documentation for list](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) specifies that `in` is an *O(n)* operation. In the worst case scenario, when the target element is not present in the list, every element will need to be visited.

Using a `set` instead of a list would improve time complexity to *O(n)* because `set` lookups would be *O(1)*.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to take advantage of set's *O(n)* time complexity to test if all characters in a string are unique is to simply convert the string sequence to a set and see if its length is still the same:

```
def unique(s):
    return len(s) == len(set(s))
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Very simple and clean.